# Using IsOperationAllowedOnDocument in RavenDB returns InvalidSystemOperation exception

Tags: authorization, ravendb

I am new to RavenDB and need assistance with authorization at the document level.  I receive the following exception when I use the Advanced.IsOperationAllowedOnDocument:

TestRavenDB.TestSuite.CanAssignRoleToUser:
System.InvalidOperationException :

## Could not figure out what to do

Your request didn't match anything that Raven knows to do, sorry...

----> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

My code is:

```
string operation = "Workflow/ApproveVacation";
string geddyUser = "Authorization/Users/glee";

var workflow = WorkflowMother.SpawnWorkflow();
var docStore = GetDocStore();
TruncateWorkflowDocuments(docStore);

using(var s = docStore.OpenSession())
{
    s.Store(new AuthorizationUser()
        {
            Name = "Geddy Lee",
                    Id = geddyUser,
                    Roles = { "Authorization/Roles/BandLeader" }
    });

        s.Store(workflow);

    s.SetAuthorizationFor(workflow, new DocumentAuthorization
        {
            Permissions = 
                {
                    new DocumentPermission
                        {
                            Allow = true,
                                Operation = operation,
                                Role = "Authorization/Roles/BandLeader"
                        }
                }
    });

    s.SaveChanges();
}

using(var s = docStore.OpenSession())
{       
    var operationResults = s.Advanced.IsOperationAllowedOnDocument(geddyUser, operation, workflow.Id);
        Assert.IsTrue(operationResults.IsAllowed);

}
```

It seems that an http request is being made using the "Workflow/ApproveVacation" as an http command like POST or GET.  Am I misinterpreting the using of IsOperationAllowedOnDocument?

**Edit**

I looked at the metadata for the document and the permission have been added:

```
"Permissions": [
      {
        "Operation": "Workflow/ApproveVacation",
        "User": null,
        "Role": "Authorization/Roles/BandLeader",
        "Allow": true,
        "Priority": 0
      }
```

**Edit 2**

Looking at the code I discovered the method GetAuthorizationFor method on the DocumentSession class.  It returns a DocumentPermission object that contains the permissions for the document which includes info on the operation.  I guess I can use this but I am still confused by the purpose of the IsOperationAllowedOnDocument method.

**Edit 3**

Using curl I experimented fired off different requests to my Raven server.  Using this line yielded the 400 error:

```
curl http://bho-vm36:8080/authorization/IsAllowed/Authorization/Users/glee?operation=Workflow/ApproveVaca‌​tion&id=workflows/15361 -v
```

There is no "endpoint" to process this request.  Without stepping through the source I am assuming that this is what the code is creating for me as the request.

Comment: Look at the actual content of the request, it will tell you what happened.

Comment: @Ayende: GET /authorization/IsAllowed/Authorization/Users/glee?operation=Workflow/ApproveVacation&id=workflows/15361.  I have PUTs for the AuthorizationUser and the Workflow object.  I don't see anything for the SetAuthorizationFor method.

Comment: @Ayende:  got it.  It's called RTFM!!!  I SLOWLY read the Authorization bundle doc and paid attention to the install instructions.  Really like where RavenDB is headed for me and my team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ayende got me thinking along the right track.  The Authorization bundle was not installed on the server, hence the error message stating that "authorization" was unknown (400 Bad Request).  Messing with curl and sending http requests to the Raven server help me get oriented.  The messages returned by the server console app was where I started for creating the requests "by hand".

**Steps for solution:**

1. Edit the Raven.Server.exe.config and add the key

   `<add key="Raven/Plugins" value="~\Plugins"/>`
2. Create folder named Plugins in Server directory
3. Copy Raven.Bundles.Authorization.dll to plugins

Doc regarding Authorization is [here](http://ravendb.net/bundles/authorization).